# cant't delete duplicate word in python array

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop, count

i am trying to delete duplicate words from python, everything works, but "Kate" word is still duplicated. help me

```
def custom_function(list):
sia = []
for item in list:
    sia.append(item.capitalize())

for word in sia:
    while sia.count(word) != 1:
        sia.remove(word)
        if sia.count(word) == 1:
            break


return sia



unknown_list = ["toby", "James", "kate", "George", "James", "rick", "Alex", 
"Jein", "Alex", "Alex","George", "Jein", "kate", "medelin"]

print(custom_function(unknown_list))
```

Comment: You shouldn't alter the list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: All this when you could just do `set([name.capitalize() for name in lst])`.

Comment: Please never *edit* and iterate over a list concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows using list [copy()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) method:

```
def custom_function(list):

    sia = []
    for item in list:
        sia.append(item.capitalize())

    sia_orig = sia.copy()
    for word in sia_orig:

        while True:
            if sia.count(word) != 1:
                sia.remove(word)
                if sia.count(word) == 1:
                    break
            else:
                break

    return sia

unknown_list = ["toby", "James", "kate", "George", "James", "rick", "Alex", 
"Jein", "Alex", "Alex","George", "Jein", "kate", "medelin"]

print(custom_function(unknown_list))
```

**Output:**

```
['Toby', 'James', 'Rick', 'Alex', 'George', 'Jein', 'Kate', 'Medelin']
```